# 4 bytes datetime in hex convert to readable

Tags: c++, datetime, hex

I have a response from a server that was compressed and converted it to base64 string. I've decoded this response and found it to be something that looks like a soap document. Most values are in hex format. So I have a parameter datetime which stores value "\xf4\xdd|\xad\x08". I know that it is a representation of the 24.06.1982 date.

How I could convert hex value to the date format? Prefer c/c++ language.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the encoded number to an integer, you need to decide if it's big-endian or little-endian.

Since the data you have is not a string, i.e. the number is not in text but directly in binary, you cannot sanely use `sscanf()` which is a string-parsing function.

Instead, so something like this:

```
const char *buffer = "\xf4\xdd|\xad\x08";
unsigned int stamp = (((unsigned char) buffer[0]) << 24) |
                     (((unsigned char) buffer[1]) << 16) |
                     (((unsigned char) buffer[3]) << 8) |
                     ((unsigned char) buffer[4]);
```

If it's little-endian, reverse the indexing sequence (so that `buffer[0]` becomes `buffer[4]` and so on).

Comment: For me its not clear, whether the String is "\xf4\xdd|\xad\x08" or the equivalent to char[5]={0xf4,0xdd,'|',0xad,0x08};

If you inteprete it correctly, of course sscanf is the wrong choice.

Answer (score -2):

to convert that hex format to a number, you can use scanf()

```
int a,b,c,d;
sscanf(input,"\\x%x\\x%x|\\x%x\\x%x",&a,&b,&c,&d);
long result=a<<24 | b<<16 | c<<8 | d;
```

That will give you 4108168456 for the value, you provided.

What further information about the format do you have?

```
int a,b,c,d;
sscanf(input,"\\x%x\\x%x|\\x%x\\x%x",&a,&b,&c,&d);
long field1=a<<8 | b;
long field2=c<<8 | d;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. That's a problem, I don't know anything about how this form was generated. What I know I described above.

Comment: Do you have other sample date - value pairs?

Comment: And by the way, how do you think what is the meaning of vertical bar inside hex value?

Comment: It can be everything. I thought it would only be optical markup and provided you with a way to parse it as a 32bit value. It might seperate two "fields". The second "field" _could_ specify the number of days since some date, but to verify this you would need to check with more data-value pairs. (or: ask the soap service how to interprete the data)

Comment: I really don't believe in the use of `sscanf()` here, in particular the formatting string's use of `\x` doesn't make sense. Does it even compile?

Comment: I corrected the \x to \\x ; which give the string i want. I overlooked it.